# Java: BufferUtil?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to use this [class](http://www.koders.com/java/fid657C07A7A912B6DAEB87F941629D2AC390DBFDF3.aspx?s=java+texturereader#L1) with JOGL. It references BufferUtil, which I can't find anywhere. I found [documentation](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/jogl-2.x-docs/com/sun/opengl/util/BufferUtil.html), but no actual code. Eclipse doesn't suggest to import it from anywhere. What do I have to do to be able to use this code?

Comment: Have you added a reference to the `jogl.jar` file to your project?

Comment: Yes. Other JOGL classes, like GL2, work fine.

Comment: There's no jogl.jar in JOGL 2.0, it's named jogl.all.jar. There's another JAR with no AWT dependency.

Comment: jogl.all.jar has been renamed jogl-all.jar

Answer (score 10):

In NeHe tutorials for JOGL, there are many places using `BufferUtil` to create the buffers. With JOGL 2.0 we can use `com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers` instead.

For example,

`BufferUtil.newIntBuffer(BUFSIZE)` becomes `Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer(BUFSIZE)`
`BufferUtil.newByteBuffer(BUFSIZE)` becomes `Buffers.newDirectByteBuffer(BUFSIZE)`

Comment: Rather use com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers to do that. GLBuffers is mostly for internal use, it should even not be in the public API.

Comment: I updated this answer according to @gouessej's comment that we should not use `com.jogamp.opengl.util.GLBuffers ` class.

Answer (score 2):

JOGL doc is rather [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/) and [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/gluegen/javadoc/).

Use [Buffers](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/gluegen/javadoc/com/jogamp/common/nio/Buffers.html) instead of BufferUtil: com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers

[TextureIO](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/texture/TextureIO.html) has been moved into the package com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureIO in JOGL 2.0. It is not a new class, it was already in JOGL 1.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem while porting a JOGL 1.x app to JOGL 2 and found BufferUtil equivalent methods in the new gluegen library: com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers

JavaDoc: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/gluegen/javadoc/com/jogamp/common/nio/Buffers.html

Answer (score -1):

I think they pulled `BufferUtil` a while back (it looks like it never did anything super useful anyway) but since the code just allocates a new `ByteBuffer`, you don't need it. Just do a `ByteBuffer unpackedPixels = ByteBuffer.allocate(packedPixels.length * bytesPerPixel);` instead.

There's also a newer JOGL class that does something similar called [`com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureIO`](http://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/jogl-latest/javadoc_dev/com/jogamp/opengl/util/texture/TextureIO.html) with a few `newTexture(...)` methods.

Comment: TextureIO absolutely replaces exactly what this class is trying to do. Just ignore this class and use the built-in TextureIO.

Comment: Your suggestion is wrong because you create an indirect byte buffer potentially not respecting the native order. We should always use the helper class Buffers to avoid doing it. Badly allocated buffers may cause problems, some methods only supports direct NIO buffers.